# Series expansion of $\exp(-x)$ without alternating terms?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Is there a series expansion of $\exp(-x)$ that does not have alternating terms?

Sorry for the ambiguity. I want a power series, but since powers of $x$ blow up as $x\to \infty$ and powers of $\frac{1}{x}$ blow up as $x \to 0$, I was wondering if a series using powers of $\frac{1}{1+x}$ exist?

Comment: What kind of series do you allow ?

Comment: What about $\frac {1}{e^x}$ using as denominator Taylor series of $e^x$ ?

Comment: Sure, $e^{-x} = e^{-x} + 0 + 0 + 0 + \dots$

Comment: [This answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1124876) might be related. It describes a way to compute $e^{-x}$ without losing computational significance to cancellation.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: that is pretty much what I did in the answer I cite above.

Comment: @robjohn. Thank you for the link ! I really appreciate what you gave in the answer (numerical aspects are main main concerns). Cheers :-)

Answer (score 3):

Here's a series of strictly positive terms:
$$\exp(-x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty{\exp(-x-n\log2)}$$

Edit: Generally, suppose that $\exp(-x)=\sum f_n(x)$, where each $f_n$ is a strictly positive function. Then $f_n$ can't be a polynomial, since polynomials blow up as $x\to\infty$, whereas $0<f_n(x)<\exp(-x)$. So any series that we find is going to have to involve more interesting functions, like the shifted exponentials in my series above.

Comment: Can we use powers of $\frac{1}{1+x}$?

Comment: Nope, $1/(1+x)$ kind-of comes closer to working, but $\exp(-x)$ approaches $0$ much faster than that function or any other rational function.